# Difference of Keras' ZeroPadding2D in TensorFlow v1 and v2?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, tensorflow2.0

I recently finished the Deep Learning Course in Coursera by Andrew Ng for Convolutional Networks. The last assignment concludes face recognition. I want to migrate the code from this assignment, which uses TensorFlow 1.2.1, to a recent version (I am using TensorFlow 2.2.0).

Let's observe following code from the assignment using tf 1.2.1:

```
  from keras.layers import Conv2D, ZeroPadding2D, Activation, Input, concatenate
  X_input = Input(input_shape)
  X = ZeroPadding2D((3, 3))(X_input)
```

where `input_shape = (3, 96, 96)`. The shapes of X_input and X are as follows (executed with `print` in Coursera's Notebook):

```
(?, 3, 96, 96)   # shape of X_input
(?, 3, 102, 102) # shape of X
```

However when I try to run the exact same code in my Notebook on Google Colab with tf 2.2.0, the shapes are:

```
(None, 3, 96, 96)  # shape of X_input
(None, 9, 102, 96) # shape of X
```

It seems to me that `ZeroPadding2D` works differently. Is that right? How can I perform zero padding to achieve the same shapes as the ones in the assignment (without touching the channels)?

Thanks!

EDIT:
The code block in my personal notebook:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, AveragePooling2D, ZeroPadding2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, Dense, Lambda

X_input = Input(input_shape)
print(X_input.shape)
X = ZeroPadding2D((3, 3))(X_input)
print(X.shape)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the code,

```
X = ZeroPadding2D((3, 3))(X_input)
```

with

```
X = ZeroPadding2D(padding = ((3, 3), (3,3)), data_format='channels_first')(X_input)
```

will give you the expected results.

Complete working code is shown below:

```
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Conv2D, MaxPool2D, AveragePooling2D, ZeroPadding2D, BatchNormalization, Activation, Dense, Lambda
input_shape = (3, 96, 96)
X_input = Input(input_shape)
print(X_input.shape)
X = ZeroPadding2D(padding = ((3, 3), (3,3)), data_format='channels_first')(X_input)
print(X.shape)
```

Comment: Thanks, this definitely did help!